# How to add image in the library

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the image path manipulate from database with php. Now how can i have to import those image in the library so that i can use them as a symbol. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load it into library, but you can load this image via php and use it on stage with action script. Take a look at this answer to the similar question:

[Load image dynamicly in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709257/load-image-dynamicly-in-flash/7709419#7709419)

Answer (score 0):

You can download it to the server and generate source file with Class that have field like this:

```
 class Library
 { 
   [Embed(source = 'path_to_folder/image_name.png')] public static var imageClass : Class;
 }
```

Alsou you should refer this class somewhere to be sure it will be compiled into your swf and use it like this:

```
 const image:Bitmap = new (Library.imageClass)();
```

In that case you need to recompile your swf every time the image is changed.

But I'm totaly agree with Bartek that it is better to use dynamic loading.